# zend database error output

Tags: zend-framework

I cant see my error of Sql. It cuts my queries, and the error is meaningless except it informs there is an error. 
Like
error in statement "select * from o.."

how can I get full query, so i can investigate how the error occured?

I previously wrote a sql function that throws debugging string if sql has error. I though zend'ers have needed and there should exists a code:

```
if(($error = mysql_error($conn)){
  $cagiri=debug_backtrace();
  $i=count($cagiri);
```

And says

```
  [Caller__Function__] => dbSave
  [Caller__Class__] => classBasic
  [Arguments] => Array
  (
   [0] => function : loadLinks
   [1] => 
   [1] => sql error: Duplicate entry 'http://www.istanbulboncugu.com/Lokma' for key 'url'
   [2] => query: insert into downloadLinks set `title`= 'Lokma : İstanbul - Avrupa', `url`= 'http://www.istanbulboncugu.com/Lokma', `site`= 'rssSehirFirsati', `status`= 'new'
```

So I dont dig 30 query, if there is error,
Error string shows function that composed the query. Etc.
I think Zend have lacks that kind of awareness. 
I know zend  not prefers hard and log path against smart ways ?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I start using that code, if there is error.

```
function results($q){
  $results  = Array();
  try{
    $results =  $this->_db->query($q)->fetchAll();
  }catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($q);
    die($e->getMessage());
  }
  return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Zend_Db_Select you can get the full created query by doing

```
$select->__toString();
```

In reply to your comment, this is how you can get the SQL error message:

```
try {
    $this->db->insert('Users', $array );
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: you can also type `echo $select;` - same thing.

Comment: dude, I meant when there is error. Of course I can print my sqls.